# Como encontrar um valor entre duas tags em um texto HTML? Sem ser com "XPATH"

Tags: python, python-3.x, scraping, urllib

Estou tentando extrair o valor entre duas tags HTML com Python, preciso que seja entre duas tags mesmo.

Eu estava fazendo desta forma para extrair valores de um catálogo de uma loja. Mas agora tenho uma necessidade de extrair valor de um produto específico. Ou seja, de uma página de produto. Gostaria de fazer algo próximo ao 'Posex' do Delphi.

A idéia é baixar o conteúdo HTML da página, fazer uma busca de uma string no texto, utilizando uma String inicial e String final e me retornar o valor entre as duas.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "https://www.panvel.com/panvel/main.do"
pagina = urlopen(url)
texto = pagina.read().decode('utf8')
texto = texto.replace("\t", "")

lista = texto.split("\n")
lista = texto.replace('\n', '')

htmlInicio = '<span class="box-produto__detalhes-nome">'
htmlFim = '</span>'
contador = 0

while contador < len(lista):
    if lista[contador].startswith(htmlInicio):
        #print(lista[contador])
        nEncontrado1 = len(htmlInicio)+(lista[contador].index(htmlInicio))
        nEncontrado2 = lista[contador].index(htmlFim)
        nomeProduto = lista[contador][nEncontrado1:nEncontrado2]

        #print(nomeProduto)
    contador+=1
```

Comment: E por que a solução é tão específica que impossibilita o uso do xpath, que resolve o problema de forma simples?

Comment: Você tem que ajudar quem está te ajudando! É chato responder uma pergunta da melhor forma possível, com todo capricho, pra depois saber que existe uma restrição artificial impedindo a solução. Por favor, [edite a pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/374803/edit) e descreva todas as restrições artificiais, dizendo o motivo e até onde está restrito.

Answer (score 1):

O conteúdo da página que quer extrair está estruturado com uma linguagem de markup, o HTML. Use isso a seu favor: Use um parser de html.

Recomendo o excelente `lxml.html`, pois ele funciona com **XPATH**!!:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import lxml.html

url = "https://www.panvel.com/panvel/main.do"
pagina = urlopen(url)
texto = pagina.read().decode('utf8')

doc = lxml.html.fromstring(texto)

spans = doc.xpath("//span[@class='box-produto__detalhes-nome']")
for span in spans:
    print(span.text_content())
```

O resultado:

```
Kit Lenços Umedecidos Huggies Classic C/48 Unidades  Le(...)
Lenço Umedecido Huggies One & Done C/48 Unidades
Shampoo Seco Panvel Hair Therapy 150ml
Lencos Umedecidos Huggies Turma Monica Primeiros 100 Di(...)
Lenços Umedecidos Huggies Classic C/48 Unidades
...
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas é para um fim especifico, e pro momento eu  não poderia usar xpath, por mais que seja pratico e melhor na minha opinião! valeu

Comment: @MarcosSilveira então você deve colocar essa restrição artificial na sua pergunta, de preferência com o motivo!